# Responsive div above image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making my commerce store responsive. I am trying to maintain the integrity of a div that is positioned absolutely above an image. I have searched for a way to keep the height of the div relative to the height of the image, but all solutions seem to rely on the div not being positioned absolutely, which it must be to sit on top of the image. Whatever I do, the problem is maintaining the apparent distance between the bottom of the div and the bottom of the image. If the browser window is shrunk, the div juts out over the image.

Code:

```
<div class="relative">
    <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0200/9900/t/6/assets/header-tiny-lr.jpg?20879">
    <div class="collection-header-wrap">
            <div class="collection-description">
                <h2>Teeny-Tiny Fun</h2>
                <p>Cuteness abounds in our collection of tiny stickers, which are great for decorating documents or belongings.</p>
                <p>Bring some fun to home or office with a few sheets of kawaii mini-stickers. These stickers might be small, but they're guaranteed deliver big smiles.</p> 
            </div>
    </div>  
</div>


.relative {
   max-width: 740px;
   position: relative;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
}

.collection-description {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 25.675675675676%; /* 190/740 */
   height: 160px;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 1;
}
```

Here's a codepen of the same: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ctdbv

Thanks

Comment: So you want the text box to stay inside the image and your issue is that it is growing in height rather than shrinking inside of the image?

Comment: yeah...that's exactly correct. i'd like to keep a percentage-calcualted border between the outside of the div and the edge of the image on three side (top, bottom, left). now it's at 10px. also, i'm not concerned by the text -- i'll remove the second <p> with a breakpoint later. thanks

Comment: You might be able to use a media query for the div and <p> to create style attributes per resolution range.

Comment: thanks. i am going to put in some media queries later, but i was hoping to squeeze this div a bit before that point. i experimented with creating a wrap around the div that i tried to get to match the image, but that didn't seem to work, either. the problem was just the space at the bottom (between the div and the bottom of the image) - cheers